# Netplan static route

Tags: netplan

I have IP **X/31** and gateway **Y** and would like to add following route to interface **eno1**:

```
ip route add Y dev eno1  
ip route add default via Y
```

How can I do that with netplan?

Comment: Well you may want to check the below post https://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/adding-persistent-static-routes-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-higher-using-netplan/
or the netplan homepage examples https://netplan.io/examples/
sections
Reaching a directly connected gateway,
Configuring source routing